# Java case statement not initializing variable

Tags: java, switch-statement

I can get my code to work if i comment out the month from the JOptionPane.  It seems like the switch case is not setting the variable publicly (if that makes sence).
Here is my code.

```
    String[] sDateIn = jTextField1.getText().split("/");
    int mDate = Integer.parseInt(sDateIn[0]);
    int dDate = Integer.parseInt(sDateIn[1]);
    int yDate = Integer.parseInt(sDateIn[2]);
    String month;
    switch (mDate) {
        case 1:
            month = "Jan";
            break;
        case 2:
            month = "Feb";
            break;
        case 3:
            month = "Mar";
            break;
        case 4:
            month = "Apr";
            break;
        case 5:
            month = "May";
            break;
        case 6:
            month = "Jun";
            break;
        case 7:
            month = "Jul";
            break;
        case 8:
            month = "Aug";
            break;
        case 9:
            month = "Sep";
            break;
        case 10:
            month = "Oct";
            break;
        case 11:
            month = "Nov";
            break;
        default:
            month = "Dec";
            break;
    }        
    //display output
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "The converted date is " + Month + " " + dDate + ", " + yDate);
```

Comment: How do you know it's not initializing?

Comment: It looks like `month` is initialized properly.  Did you intend for `Month` (capitalized) to be another variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you are appending `Month` instead of `month`.

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "The converted date is " + month /*Month to month*/ + " " + dDate + ", " + yDate);
```